# How to count the length of json returned using Postman?

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I send a request which sends me back something like:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 86154,
            ...
        },
        {
            "id": 86194,
            ...
        }
}
```

I would like to count the size of this array in Postman test section. So I wrote:

```
var body = JSON.parse(pm.response.json());
tests["Count: "  + body.items] = true;
```

[image]

As you can see above, it didn't worked. I am new to both PostMan and Javascript, that's probably why.

Comment: FYI re your [currently-accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61499775/157247): There's no reason whatsoever for using `Object.keys` here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Count: "  + Object.keys(body.items).length] = true;
```

I suppose postman return json and might not always need to parse it, You then count the length of your "items" using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and *why* it solves the problem. *(not my downvote)*

Comment: I would advise against using the older syntax, this will at some point, be removed from the app and you should really be migrating over to the newer style.

Answer (score 10):

Simple answer is to get the same thing, using the new `pm.*` API syntax:

```
pm.test(`Count: ${pm.response.json().items.length}`)
```

The syntax you used is incorrect `JSON.parse(pm.response.json())` - You can just use `pm.response.json()` and drop the `JSON.parse()`.

To get the number of objects, you just need to use the [.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property.

I'm not sure *what* you are testing for but this simple test would check or assert that you have 2 objects (Like your example) in the array:

```
let body = pm.response.json()
pm.test("Check the Items array length", () => {
    pm.expect(body.items.length).to.equal(2)
})
```

This is using the newer `pm.test()` syntax, more about this and all the other `pm.*` API methods can be found here:

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman-sandbox-api-reference/

If you just wanted to log out the value and not add that to a test, you can use `console.log(pm.response.json().items.length)` in the `Tests` tab and see this displayed in the Postman Console.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I *always* get those mixed up! :(

Answer (score 2):

`.json()` returns an promise. try it like this:

```
(async () => {
   var body = await pm.response.json();
   tests["Count: "  + body.items] = true; 
})()
```

or like this:

```
pm.response.json().then(body => {
   tests["Count: "  + body.items] = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the test in the postman, and then inside that you can check the no of object in the response as shown in below code.

```
pm.test("Item count should be 5", function () {
  var jsonData = pm.response.json();
  pm.expect(jsonData.items.length).to.eql(5);
});
```

I have used a static count, but in your test scripts you can also use dynamic variables